# Change text color within cell using cell formula or calling custom function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

Probably basic question but I couldn't find a way to change text color via cell formula.
I need something like:

```
="This is simple text. "&colorText("And this is orange text", "#ff9900")
```

In other words I simply need to have a way to change text color via formula. This way I can have in the same cell text with different colors.

Is something like this possible? Maybe I'd need to create a custom function? Couldn't find anything except this but it's not exactly what I need:

```
function setFontAndBackgroundColorCell() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var cell = sheet.getRange('B2');
  cell.setFontColor('yellow');
  cell.setBackground('red');
  cell.setValue('TEST');
}
```

If I use it this way:

```
="This is simple text. "&setFontAndBackgroundColorCell("And this is orange text", "#ff9900")
```

The sheet outputs this error:

```
Exception: You do not have permission to call setFontColor (line 26).
```

Comment: Unfortunately, cells can hold formulas or rich text. But not both. Meaning that you can't format your text like that with a formula.

Comment: please cross reference your other posts when you do it on multiple platforms like this:
https://www.reddit.com/r/sheets/comments/u7abcy/change_text_color_within_cell_using_cell_formula/

https://www.reddit.com/r/googlesheets/comments/u7abo2/change_text_color_within_cell_using_cell_formula/